# C# ECDSA with private key with curve secp224k1

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I am trying to generate r and s values of an ECDSA signature according to https://github.com/coinfloor/API/blob/master/AUTH.md in c#.

My code matches their sample values until step 9.

Generation of r and s values in step 10 uses randomness so it can't match sample values.

However, when I replace sample userid, clientCookie, password values with my actual account data and send authentication api message then I always get error: {"error_code":7,"error_msg":"You sent an incorrect signature. This probably means you used a wrong passphrase."}

I use BouncyCastle library.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ulong userid = 1;
    string clientCookie = "HGREqcILTz8blHa/jsUTVTNBJlg=";
    string password = "opensesame";

    string servernonce = "azRzAi5rm1ry/l0drnz1vw==";
    var noncebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(servernonce);
    byte[] clientnonce = StringToByteArray("f08c98caf1fd82e8cea9825dbff04fd0"); // == 8IyYyvH9gujOqYJdv/BP0A==
    //Random random = new Random();
    //byte[] clientnonce = new byte[16];
    //random.NextBytes(clientnonce);

    // step 7
    byte[] _40bytearray = new byte[40];
    byte[] useridByte = ToByteArray(userid);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(useridByte, 0, _40bytearray, 0, useridByte.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(noncebytes, 0, _40bytearray, useridByte.Length, noncebytes.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(clientnonce, 0, _40bytearray, useridByte.Length + noncebytes.Length, clientnonce.Length);

    // step 8
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    byte[] seedBytes = new byte[useridByte.Length + passwordBytes.Length];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(useridByte, 0, seedBytes, 0, useridByte.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(passwordBytes, 0, seedBytes, useridByte.Length, passwordBytes.Length);

    // step 9
    Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha224Digest myHash = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha224Digest();
    myHash.BlockUpdate(seedBytes, 0, seedBytes.Length);
    byte[] seedbytesSHA224 = new byte[myHash.GetDigestSize()];
    myHash.DoFinal(seedbytesSHA224, 0);

    // step 10
    Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X9.X9ECParameters spec = Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X9.ECNamedCurveTable.GetByName("secp224k1");
    Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECDomainParameters domain = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECDomainParameters(spec.Curve, spec.G, spec.N, spec.H);
    Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers.ECDsaSigner signer = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers.ECDsaSigner(new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers.HMacDsaKCalculator(new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha224Digest()));
    Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECPrivateKeyParameters privkey = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECPrivateKeyParameters(new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, seedbytesSHA224), domain);
    signer.Init(true, privkey);
    Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature(_40bytearray);
    byte[] r = signature[0].ToByteArrayUnsigned();
    byte[] s = signature[1].ToByteArrayUnsigned();

    // step 11, 12
    Console.WriteLine("{\"method\":\"Authenticate\",\"user_id\":" + userid + ",\"cookie\":\"" + clientCookie + "\",\"nonce\":\"" + Convert.ToBase64String(clientnonce) + "\",\"signature\":[\"" + Convert.ToBase64String(r) + "\",\"" + Convert.ToBase64String(s) + "\"]}");
}

public static byte[] ToByteArray(this ulong value)
{
    return new byte[] { (byte)(value >> 56), (byte)(value >> 48), (byte)(value >> 40), (byte)(value >> 32), (byte)(value >> 24), (byte)(value >> 16), (byte)(value >> 8), (byte)(value) };
}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}
```

they have libraries for authentication in

C: https://github.com/coinfloor/libecp

java: https://github.com/coinfloor/java-library/blob/983e6d506d6e4ef70ffddb21991f85c7bbc3a2eb/src/main/java/uk/co/coinfloor/api/Coinfloor.java

ruby: https://github.com/coinfloor/ruby-libecp/blob/master/lib/libecp.rb

python: https://github.com/coinfloor/python-library/blob/master/coinfloor.py

Any ideas why r and s values generated in my c# code don't work?

Comment: *... until step 9...* So your sha224 hashes differ?

Comment: The problem appears to be that you haven't hashed the message `_40bytearray` prior to signing it. Also, make certain you know what you are doing when using a deterministic k method.

Comment: No. My sha 224 generates in step 9 matches their sample. The issue starts from step 10

Comment: You were right. The issue was that I haven't hashed the _40bytearray. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding "make certain you know what you are doing when using a deterministic k method." my `byte[] clientnonce` is supposed to be randomly generates array. In this code it was commented out and replaced with a fixed value to match their sample values. I believe with having this randomly generated it makes usage of non deterministic method unnecessary, right? The message is also sent through secured websocket connection so I believe it is fine.

Comment: The randomness is not the issue. In fact, there probably is no issue at all. My only discomfort is that there is a slight disagreement between the Bouncycastle implementation and the [relevant standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6979). In the standard it is the original message that is used to generate k, but in this bouncycastle implementation it is the hash of the message that is used. The difference should not matter securitywise but any deviation makes me nervous.